# Theme Customization API and child themes

Tags: child-theme, parent-theme, theme-customizer

I've recently developed a parent theme that makes heavy use of the Theme Customization API. Is there an easy way to port these settings when a user activates one of my child themes? Currently, the data previously saved in the Customize screen disappears when activating a child theme. Of course, once they reactivate the parent theme, the settings return.

Any dealt with this yet?

Comment: Are you using the Settings API or the Theme Mods API for your Theme settings/Theme Customizer integration?

Comment: Using Theme Mod. All settings on the "Customize" screen, calling them in my theme with get_theme_mod.

Answer (score 1):

There is already an answer about this question with explicable examples [How do I get a parent theme modification from a child theme?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/189144/how-do-i-get-a-parent-theme-modification-from-a-child-theme).

You can also check about `get_theme_mod` here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_theme_mod/