# How do I get a parent theme modification from a child theme?

Tags: theme-development, themes, child-theme, theme-customizer

I've built a child theme, and I would like to reuse some of the settings created by the parent. I hoped this would be as easy as `get_theme_mod( 'setting' )` inside the child theme, but that returns nothing.

I found [a feature request](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/27177) that addresses this very thing which leads me to believe WP doesn't offer an easy way to get to those parent theme settings. Has anyone found a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

[If you look at how the code works](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/theme.php#L0), you should notice that theme mods are saved in the `*_options` table under `theme_mods_{theme_slug}` with the theme slug being, as near as I can tell, the directory name containing the theme stylesheet, so:

```
$ptheme = get_template_directory();
$theme_slug = basename($ptheme);
$mods = get_option( "theme_mods_$theme_slug");
```

As a function:

```
function get_parent_theme_mods($mod = '') {
  $ptheme = get_template_directory();
  $theme_slug = basename($ptheme);
  $mods = get_option( "theme_mods_{$theme_slug}");
  if (!empty($mods) && isset($mods[$mod])) {
    $mods = $mods[$mod];
  }
  return $mods;
}
var_dump(get_parent_theme_mods());
var_dump(get_parent_theme_mods('background_color'));
```

Comment: I've implemented this, but it didn't seem to work. Logged all the variables out and found that `$mods` is empty. `$ptheme` and `$theme_slug` are showing the values I expect.

Comment: Have you checked the database itself for those theme mods?